# python error list index out of range ( sorting )

Tags: python-2.7

Program to sort:

```
a = [ 7 ,6,4,3,8,1 ]
i = 1
while i < 7:
     if a[i] > a[i+1]:
         l= a[i]
         a[i]=a[i+1]
         a[i+1]=l
     i+=1
print a
```

i am getting an error list index is out of range, how should i change my code to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the length of the list `a` is `6`, so the indices you can use to access to its elements are `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`.

Now, since you are using

```
a[i + 1]
```

to access to the list `a`, the maximum value `i` can take is `4` (`i+1 = 4+1 = 5` -> the maximum index you can use), so your while condition should be:

```
while i < 5:
    ...
```

or the equivalent

```
while i <= 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [ 7 ,6,4,3,8,1 ]
i = 1
while i < 5:
   if a[i] > a[i+1]:
     l= a[i]
     a[i]=a[i+1]
     a[i+1]=l
   i+=1
print a
```

I should be less than 5 here